# transparent erase in iOS- Titanium

Tags: ios, titanium, paint, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I have two images one on the above and i want to erase a small part from the top image to show the background image. Is it possible transparent erase using titanium for iOS?

Thanks and regards,
GANESH M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the [ti.paint module](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/paint/mobile/ios). Specifically, its ability to have an image on the canvas which can be erased. After installing, try this:

```
// Container window
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({ backgroundColor: '#fff' });
// Background image
var backgroundImage = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image : 'yourbgimage.png'
    width : Ti.UI.FILL,
    height : Ti.UI.FILL
});

// Require paint module and add to view with an erasable image
var Paint = require('ti.paint');
var paintView = Paint.createPaintView({
    image : 'yourfgimage.png', // This is the image you erase
    eraseMode : true,
    width : Ti.UI.FILL,
    height : Ti.UI.FILL,
    strokeColor : '#0f0', strokeAlpha : 255, strokeWidth : 10
});

win.add(backgroundImage);
win.add(paintView);
win.open();
```